# iOS: Determine if photo in photo album is from camera

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, alassetslibrary

I am trying to have my application determine if a photo in photoalbum is from camera.
The general flow I am trying to implement is

1. Application loads,
2. Application enumerates Photo album
3. If the source of the photo is Camera, then process that photo and cache its information so it can be ignored in future.

Since the "Camera roll" can be written with photos from other application, I want to detect those photos that were specifically taken using the camera.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [Technical Q&A 1622, Listing 2](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1622/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009180) for details on how to get the metadata dictionary of dictionaries (one dictionary for each metadata format) for each `ALAssetRepresentation` and grab the EXIF dictionary.

The keys of the dictionary of dictionaries can be found in the [CGImageProperties Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImageProperties_Reference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005103), along with the key names for the EXIF dictionary. From that you should be able to get the Camera Make/Model to figure out if it was taken with the phone.